# Disable or enable warnings for cppcheck using a configuration file

Tags: c++, configuration-files, cppcheck, clang-tidy

With clang-tidy static analyzer I can keep a file (`.clang-tidy`) in the root of the project with the warnings I want to activate or deactivate.
`clang-tidy` will look for this file (as far I know) and use the options defined there. This saves me from hard coding long command lines in CMake or Makefiles.

**Is it possible to do the same with `cppcheck` static analyzer?**

Currently I have this very long command line hardcoded:

```
cppcheck --max-ctu-depth=3 --enable=all --inline-suppr --suppress=*:*thrust/complex* --suppress=missingInclude --suppress=syntaxError --suppress=unmatchedSuppression --suppress=preprocessorErrorDirective --language=c++ --std=c++14 --error-exitcode=666
```

---

This is an example of `.clang-tidy` configuration file that I keep at the root of a project:

```
---
Checks: '
    *,
    -readability-magic-numbers,
    -modernize-use-nodiscard,
    -altera-struct-pack-align,
    -cert-err58-cpp,
    -cppcoreguidelines-avoid-non-const-global-variables,
    -cppcoreguidelines-macro-usage,
    -cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-array-to-pointer-decay,
    -cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-vararg,
    -cppcoreguidelines-avoid-magic-numbers,
    -fuchsia-default-arguments-calls,
    -fuchsia-trailing-return,
    -fuchsia-statically-constructed-objects,
    -fuchsia-overloaded-operator,
    -hicpp-vararg,
    -hicpp-no-array-decay,
    -llvm-header-guard,
    -llvmlibc-restrict-system-libc-headers,
    -llvmlibc-implementation-in-namespace,
    -llvmlibc-callee-namespace
'
WarningsAsErrors: '*'
HeaderFilterRegex: '.'
AnalyzeTemporaryDtors: false
FormatStyle: file
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is via `--suppressions-list=<file>` option.

For example, write the following `.suppress.cppcheck` file:

```
IOWithoutPositioning
MissingInclude
...
```

And add `--suppressions-list=./.suppress.cppcheck` to your cppcheck cmdline.

Comment: I wonder why I didn't see this option before. `--suppressions-list` should have a default value.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the configuration in a `*.cppcheck` file and then use the `--project` command line option to run the check. See [the manual](https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.html) - Cppcheck GUI project section.

`cppcheck` files are normally generated by CppCheckGUI via File -> New project file. The exact syntax is undocumented but it's basically just an XML file and looks to be fairly straightforward if you want to create the file directly without using the GUI.

Sample `test.cppcheck` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="1">
    <builddir>test2-cppcheck-build-dir</builddir>
    <platform>Unspecified</platform>
    <analyze-all-vs-configs>false</analyze-all-vs-configs>
    <check-headers>true</check-headers>
    <check-unused-templates>false</check-unused-templates>
    <max-ctu-depth>10</max-ctu-depth>
    <exclude>
        <path name="WINDOWS/"/>
    </exclude>
    <suppressions>
        <suppression>IOWithoutPositioning</suppression>
    </suppressions>
</project>
```

Comment: I tried to generate the xml from the GUI but I couldn’t even select the exceptions in the GUI yo store it in the xml. Do you have an example xml file?

Comment: Added a sample. You can add edit the .cppcheck file via gui by going to File - Edit project file.

Comment: The format is defined here https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf. XML is only one of two possible formats.

Comment: I am using these options `cppcheck --enable=all --suppress=missingIncludeSystem --inline-suppr --std=c++17 --check-config --error-exitcode=1`. It would be nice to know how to put these in an XML or text configuration file. So far I wasn't able to put any of these options in a configuration file, they are ignored.